# Solving Trigonometric Equation Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

im kinda stuck to solve the following problems below

Problem: 4cos²2x+sin2x=3   (0 < x <= π)

Steps:

4cos²2x+sin2x=3

2+2cos4x+sin2x=3

2cos4x+sin2x=1

2(1-2sin²2x)+sinx=1

2-4sin²2x+sinx=1

Bring every term to the right side

0= 1-2+4sin²2x-sinx

4sin²2x-sinx-1=0

Let M= sin2x, sin

4m²-m-1=0

X=+0.64 , x=-0.39

Comment: Your equation, and I think you meant this because of the substition $m = \sin(2x)$ should be $4\sin^2(2x) - \sin(2x) - 1 = 0$. Perhaps a typo? Also, best to represent the roots of the quadratic in $m$ as $\dfrac {1\pm \sqrt{17}}{8}$, and recall that you need to solve for $x$ such that $\sin(2x) = m_1, m_2$

Comment: Your $\sin(2x)$ seems to have magically turned into $\sin(x)$ along the way. Be careful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:
$$4\cos^2(2x)+\sin(2x) = 3$$

Use $\cos^2(2x) = 1-\sin^2(2x)$ then:

$$4(1-\sin^2(2x))+\sin(2x) = 3\implies4-4\sin^2(2x) + \sin(2x) = 3\implies\\1+\sin(2x)-4\sin^2(2x) = 0$$

which has roots:

$$\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{17})\\\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{8}(1+\sqrt{17})$$

For the first equations:

$$\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{17})\implies \sin^{-1}\sin(2x) = \sin^{-1}\frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{17})\implies \\2x = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{17})\right)\implies x = \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{17})\right)}{2}$$
But there is also another solution in the other quadrant such that:

$$2x = \pi - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{17})\right)\implies\\x = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{8}(1-\sqrt{17})\right)}{2}$$

You have to do the same thing for the second root:

$$\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{8}(1+\sqrt{17})$$

And then you have the answer

Comment: I have applied using quadratic formulae and i'm confused with the next step..

Comment: When you use the quadratic formuma, you substituted $m =\sin(2x)$, then you have that $\sin(2x) = 0.64...$ which is just an approximation. If you don't need the exact value, you can do: $\sin(2x) = 0.64$ and $\sin(2x) = -0.39$, and then $$\sin^{-1}\sin(2x) = 0.64 \implies 2x = \sin^{-1}(0.64) \implies x = \frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}(0.64)$$ The same for the root $-0.39$

Comment: Notice, also, that in the interval $[0,\pi]$ there is also another value that the sine function can have (its simetric around the $y$-axis) that is: $2x = \pi - \sin^{-1}(0.64)$. If you don't remember, note that $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ has the solutions $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $x = \pi -\frac{\pi}{6}$ (the simetric of $\frac{pi}{6}$ around the $y$-axis) in the interval $[0, \pi]$